# Performance Improvement on SQL Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the following script which causes performance degradation and not sure how to enhance performance on it and in SSIS script task this part of the code time out.

```
INSERT INTO
   dbo.GEMS_CIX_FL_C_ARCHIVE ([ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID], [CollectionID], [CollectionTypeCode], [InstallationPointID], [NameSpecificationName], [PropertyReferenceID], [RECORDSENTERED], [XmlFile], LoadedDate) 
   SELECT
      [ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID],
      [CollectionID],
      [CollectionTypeCode],
      [InstallationPointID],
      [NameSpecificationName],
      [PropertyReferenceID],
      [RECORDSENTERED],
      [XmlFile],
      '2018-12-13 14:27:15' 
   FROM
      dbo.SSIS_SPT_FC_FL_CW_D001 
   WHERE
      ISNULL(InstallationPointID, '') + ISNULL(PropertyReferenceID, '') + ISNULL(NameSpecificationName, '') IN 
      (
         SELECT
            ISNULL(InstallationPointID, '') + ISNULL(PropertyReferenceID, '') + ISNULL(NameSpecificationName, '') 
         FROM
            dbo.GEMS_CIX_FL_C 
         WHERE
            ISNULL(InstallationPointID, '') + ISNULL(PropertyReferenceID, '') + ISNULL(NameSpecificationName, '') + ISNULL(XmlFile, '') NOT IN 
            (
               SELECT
                  ISNULL( InstallationPointID, '') + ISNULL(PropertyReferenceID, '') + ISNULL(NameSpecificationName, '') + ISNULL(XmlFile, '') 
               FROM
                  dbo.GEMS_CIX_FL_C_ARCHIVE
            )
      )


     [dbo].[GEMS_CIX_FL_C_ARCHIVE]
                                 ([ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID] [nvarchar](500)NULL, 
                              [CollectionID] [nvarchar](500) NULL, 
                                  [CollectionTypeCode][nvarchar](500) NULL,
                              [InstallationPointID] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
                                  [NameSpecificationName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
                                  [PropertyReferenceID][nvarchar](500) NULL,
                                  [RECORDSENTERED] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
                                  [XmlFile] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
                                  [LoadedDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL )


     [dbo].[GEMS_CIX_FL_C]
     ([ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
     [CollectionID] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
     [CollectionTypeCode][nvarchar](500) NULL,
     [InstallationPointID] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
     [NameSpecificationName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
     [PropertyReferenceID][nvarchar](500) NULL,
     [RECORDSENTERED] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
     [XmlFile] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
     [LoadedDate] [nvarchar](50) NULL )


 [dbo].[SSIS_SPT_FC_FL_CW_D001](
    [InstallationPointID] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [PropertyReferenceID] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [NameSpecificationName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [CollectionID] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [CollectionTypeCode] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [RECORDSENTERED] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [XmlFile] [nvarchar](500) NULL
```

at present moment no indexes created in any of the above tables. what index is required?

Insert

[image: X]

delete

[image: X]

Insert into

[image: X]

Comment: You've written an extremely poor SE:ECT statement. It's impossible to improve it without the database schema (tables), sample data, and the execution plan of the statement. All of the string + and ISNULL calls make indexes useless.  Those function calls slow things down, as does the sub-SELECT and NOT IN in the WHERE clause, and the string concatenation, and a SELECT * is almost always bad because it fetches columns you don't use or need. A good SQL tutorial might be helpful to you. (I'm not sure why your question title says INSERT when you don't have an INSERT anywhere in your SQL.)

Comment: Thanks, I have added the complete code now. Apologies!

Comment: Your addition fixes the discrepancy between the title and SQL, but does not address the table definitions, sample data, and execution plan for the statement. Without those, the only thing to say is that you need to correct all of the issues that I mentioned above (the repeated calls to ISNULL, the string +, the sub-select with NOT IN, etc.). I still recommend a good basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: Added the execution plans. No indexes created at present.

Comment: Added the table definitions

Comment: Creating persistent computed columns for those ISNULL+ISNULL+ISNULL "fields" and indexing them might help. Then you need to use the computed columns in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement that I can give you without understanding your model data is to avoid:

```
SELECT *
```

Select all is a bad practice, where you will get a lot of not necessary resources that can cause you performance degradation, the rest of the query looks very straightforward to me